# systemd-resolved and systemd-timesyncd timeout failure, keep trying to restart

Tags: server, 18.04, systemd-resolved, systemd-timesyncd

After a recent update my 18.04 server is running in a degraded state (as reported by `systemctl status`) because of two failed units. In `/var/log/syslog` I get these lines every 90 s:

```
Jun 10 22:07:49 olympus systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jun 10 22:07:49 olympus systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
```

In `journalctl -xe`:

```
-- Unit systemd-timesyncd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
jun 10 22:22:52 olympus systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
jun 10 22:22:52 olympus systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
```

`systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` shows that it is `Active (activating)` all the time:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2019-06-10 22:34:54 CEST; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 14410 ((imesyncd))
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4302)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─14410 (imesyncd)

jun 10 22:34:54 olympus systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
```

After 1m 30s it gives up and restarts. The same goes for `systemd-resolvd`.

Apart from this activity (and the huge number of messages it generates) the server appears to work well.

What is really wrong with these units? How can I debug the problem?

EDIT: output of requested commands. There is nothing in `/etc/netplan/` nor in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`.

```
jos@olympus:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65 jan 30 09:46 /etc/resolv.conf
jos@olympus:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.124.254
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
jos@olympus:~$ ls /etc/netplan
jos@olympus:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
    address 192.168.124.99
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.124.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.124.254 213.75.63.75 213.75.63.76 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Does /etc/resolv.conf link to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf? Might be directly to a file with nameservers cutting system-resolvd out of the loop.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @ubfan1 indeed `/etc/resolv.conf` is a file, not a link.